# How can I check the usage of my iphone app in itunes connect?

Tags: analytics, app-store-connect, app-store

How can I check the usage of my iPhone app in iTunes connect?

For example, the number of times the application has been launched on the user's iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see more info in iTunes connect then the number of downloads, by date and by country

To see more, you'd need a third party analytics library built into your app, but I don't know what Apple's policies are. I've heard that [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html) is a decent analytics library, but I don't use it.